# Only run code when tab is active in R Shiny (to reduce loading times)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app, and because there is a lot of data to load and computations, it is a bit too slow to my liking. I have 2 main tabs, and the second tab contains a leaflet map. I would like to make it so that the content and script for this tab only starts running/loading once a viewer clicks the tab.

I've tried to do this with observeEvent, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

I currently have this script for the second tab in my server (won't post the whole server script, since it's kinda long and it's only for first tab)

```
  observeEvent(input$coronahulp_tab, {

   coronahulp <- search_tweets("coronahulp", n=1000, include_rts=FALSE, lang = 'nl', token = t)
   coronahulp2 <- coronahulp %>%  mutate(text, tolower(text)) %>%
      mutate(hashtags, tolower(hashtags)) %>%
      select(created_at, text, hashtags, location)

  woonplaatsen <- read_delim("Woonplaatsen_locatie.csv", delim = ";")
  woonplaatsen$woonplaatsnaam <- tolower(woonplaatsen$woonplaatsnaam)

  woonplaats_vector <- woonplaatsen$woonplaatsnaam

  coronahulp_locatie1 <- coronahulp2 %>% select(created_at, location) %>%
    mutate(location = tolower(location)) %>%
    mutate(nieuw = str_extract(location, paste("\\b",woonplaats_vector,"\\b", collapse = "|", sep = ""))) %>%
    filter(!(nieuw %in% c("nederland"))) %>%
    filter(!(is.na(nieuw))) %>%
    select(created_at, nieuw)


  coronahulp_locatie2 <- coronahulp2 %>% select(created_at, text) %>%
    mutate(text = tolower(text)) %>%
    mutate(nieuw = str_extract(text, paste("\\b",woonplaats_vector,"\\b", collapse = "|", sep = ""))) %>%
    filter(!(nieuw %in% c("de wijk", "buren", "hoeven", "anderen", "hem", "heel","een", "zetten", "nederland", "handel", "best", "echt"))) %>%
    filter(!(is.na(nieuw))) %>%
    select(created_at, nieuw)

  coronahulp_locatie3 <- coronahulp2 %>% select(created_at, hashtags) %>%
    mutate(hashtags = tolower(hashtags)) %>%
    unnest(hashtags)%>%
    mutate(nieuw = str_extract(hashtags, paste("\\b",woonplaats_vector,"\\b", collapse = "|", sep = ""))) %>%
    filter(!(nieuw %in% c("de wijk", "buren", "hoeven", "anderen", "hem", "heel","een", "zetten", "nederland", "handel", "best", "echt"))) %>%
    filter(!(is.na(nieuw))) %>%
    select(created_at, nieuw)

  coronahulp_locatie <- rbind(coronahulp_locatie1,coronahulp_locatie2, coronahulp_locatie3)
  coronahulp_locatie <- coronahulp_locatie %>%
    unique() %>%
    merge(coronahulp2) %>%
    rename(woonplaatsnaam = nieuw)
  options(digits = 7)

  locatie_coronahulp <- left_join(coronahulp_locatie, woonplaatsen) %>% 
    select(text, woonplaatsnaam, long, lat) %>%
    unique() %>%
    mutate(long = as.numeric(long), lat = as.numeric(lat)) %>%
    group_by(long,lat, woonplaatsnaam) %>%
    summarise(aantal = n(),text=paste(text,collapse=' <br><br> '))

  popup <- paste("<div class='leaflet-popup-scrolled' style='max-width:600px;max-height:300px'>","<b>", capitalize(locatie_coronahulp$woonplaatsnaam),"</b>", "<br><br>",locatie_coronahulp$text, "</div>")

  output$kaartje <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(locatie_coronahulp) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, label= ~capitalize(woonplaatsnaam), popup = ~popup, radius = ~aantal, stroke = FALSE, color = "#a72f6e") %>%
      addResetMapButton() 
  })})
```

In the UI I have this for the second tab:

```
tabPanel("Coronahulp",
                          value = "coronahulp_tab",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              h2("Coronahulp", align = "center"), 
                              br(),
                              HTML("<p style='font-size:16px'>Dagelijks beginnen mensen nieuwe #coronahulp initiatieven. Wil je weten welke initiatieven er bij jou in de buurt zijn gestart?
                                  Dit kaartje laat per woonplaats de coronahulp initiatieven zien die in de afgelopen zeven dagen op Twitter zijn genoemd.</p>"),
                              tags$a(
                                href="https://www.digitalewereld.nl/", 
                                tags$img(src="digitale_wereld.png", 
                                         title="Digitale wereld", 
                                         width="190",
                                         height="90"),
                                id="digitale_wereld"
                              ),
                              actionButton("info_button2", "Meer informatie")
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              leafletOutput("kaartje", height = '1000px') %>% withSpinner(color="#dca108")
                            )
                          )
                 )
```

Is ObserveEvent the way to go? Or should I do it differently? I've already tried to wrap all script parts in seperate reactive statements, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, give an id to `tabsetPanel()` (not only `tabPanel()`) in your `ui` if it is not already the case. Then, try to put the code for the second tab in `observe({ if (input$id_of_tabsetpanel == "id_of_the_second_panel"){ .... }  })`